# Does the REST API still accept XML?

Tags: magento2, api, xml, rest-api

quick broad question. Does the REST API in Magento 2 still accept XML input? According to the introduction, it does. But further on in the documentation, there is no mention. I have been able to receive XML Formatted data (product) but I have not been able to submit any new products.

If this is still possible, is there any documentation I have overlooked?

Comment: Could you share your request XML and code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the REST API supports payloads in XML format, but it turns out they need to be specially wrapped in `magento_api` tags. The `content-type` will also need to be set to `application/xml`. Here's an example on how to create a customer:

```
<magento_api>
   <customer>
      <addresses>
         <element>
            <city>New York</city>
            <countryId>US</countryId>
            <defaultBilling>true</defaultBilling>
            <defaultShipping>true</defaultShipping>
            <firstname>Big</firstname>
            <lastname>Foot</lastname>
            <postcode>10755</postcode>
            <region>
               <region>New York</region>
               <regionCode>NY</regionCode>
            </region>
            <street>
               <element>125 Oak Ave</element>
            </street>
            <telephone>512-444-1111</telephone>
         </element>
      </addresses>
      <email>bigfoot@example.com</email>
      <firstname>Big</firstname>
      <lastname>Foot</lastname>
   </customer>
</magento_api>
```

Note that array data members will need their own tags, like the `element` tags in the example above.

Apologies for this miss in documentation, and we will work on adding this info to the topic!

Comment: On behalf of myself and my client, I like to thank you very much. All the best!

Comment: When trying this out, I discovered that the actual root node name is irrelevant: you can use `<magento_api>`, `<root>` or whatever.

Comment: @mkotov can u help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/296960/how-to-fetch-post-method-xml-data-in-magento2-controller